# DataTemplate is not recognized for DataGrid items

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid, datatemplate

I try to create a matrix like view in WPF using a DataGrid control. I populate my items source list with a DataTable available thru a converter. Each row is an array of custom class type (MatrixCell). 
In xaml, in my resource tab, I create a DataTemplate for my type, MatrixCell, but when running the application it is not applied. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
            CanUserSortColumns="False" 
            CanUserResizeColumns="False"
            SelectionUnit="Cell"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Name="matrixGrid">
            <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Path="Test" Converter="{StaticResource MatrixToDataViewConverter}"/>
            </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

My converter:

```
public class MatrixToDataViewConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var myDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
            if(value != null)
            {
                var test = value as ITest;
                myDataTable.Columns.Add("-");
                foreach (var column in test.Columns)
                {
                    //populate columns
                    //...
                }

                var rows = new List<List<MatrixCell>>();
                foreach (var matrixRow in test.MatrixRows)
                {
                    var row = new List<MatrixCell>();
                    row.Add(new MatrixCell() { Content = $"{matrixRow.Id} {matrixRow.Name}" });
                    var temp = new MatrixCell[1 + test.Columns.Count];
                    foreach (var column in test.Columns)
                    {
                        //determine the Content value for each MatrixCell
                        //...
                        row.Add(new MatrixCell() { Content = content });
                    }

                    row.CopyTo(temp);
                    myDataTable.Rows.Add(temp);
                }
            }
            return myDataTable.DefaultView;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

MatrixCell class:

```
public class MatrixCell
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public bool IsComparerDone { get; set; }

        //public override string ToString()
        //{
        //    return Content;
        //}
    }
```

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MatrixCell}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}">
                <!--<TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsComparerResult}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>-->
            </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Just for displaying the MatrixCell.Content I can override the ToString method and it works, but I would like to do it using a DataTemplate.

This is how my current application looks like:
[matrix view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY9f2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! For future reference you'll get much better answers if you provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I'll try to help...

You don't need that converter. Just bind to your list directly and declare a column of type DataGridTemplateColumn explicitly. Then inside that place a `ContentControl` and bind its `Content` property to its current DataContext (i.e. `Content="{Binding}"`). The ContentControl will then pick up your DataTemplate and populate itself accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But I do need that converter. I don't have a list to bind my ItemsSource to, but more importantly I have to recreate my columns every time depending on my "Test" filed. And the only way I know how to do that is by using a convertor.

Comment: You've tagged `data-binding`, but you're not actually doing data-binding, at least not the way WPF has been designed to use it. You do have a list of items: ITest.MatrixRows. With data-binding you prepare your data in a format that the view can readily consume, converters are used for lightweight tasks when data conversion has to go both ways (as opposed to one-way, where you typically use DataTriggers). Business logic never, ever goes in a converter, it's always a sign that the layer responsible for preparing the data for your view to consume isn't doing its job properly.

Comment: So in your case you'd declare a class call MatrixRow or something which contains a list of type MatrixCell. You business layer creates a list of these, and populate each one's list of MatrixCell with the appropriate content. This `List<MatrixRow>` is what you bind ItemsSource to. You are actually doing the right thing more-or-less, you're just doing it in the wrong place, which is causing you to also have to create the child controls manually. With proper data binding, it's the DataTemplates that are doing that work for you, you just provide the data and let it take care of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Sorry, ignore that last bit about you creating the controls manually, looking at it again I can see that's not actually what you're doing. The rest of what I've said is still valid though...the conversion of your data to a DataTable should be getting done in the layer that your ItemsSource is binding to, not inside a converter.